# RIA Services SP2 Function Complex type not visible in Object Context

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4, service, ria

I am struggling with returning a complex type from my services layer. It doesnt seem to be accessible from my object context.

This is the query in the service layer. All compiling fine.

```
    public IQueryable<USP_GetPostsByThreadID_Result> uspGetPostsByThreadID(int ThreadID)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.USP_GetPostsByThreadID(ThreadID).AsQueryable();
    }
```

When I try and call it from my client, the ForumContext is not seeing it. I checked the client generated file and nothing similar is being generated.  Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your method may not meet the expected convention for queries. Try one or both of the following:

- Add the `[Query]` attribute
- Rename the method to `GetUspPostsByThreadID`

Result:

```
[System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.Query]
public IQueryable<USP_GetPostsByThreadID_Result> GetUspPostsByThreadID(int ThreadID)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.USP_GetPostsByThreadID(ThreadID).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: That did the trick thanks! I then got the compile error about no key, which I added to the metadata class and now I can see the method in the client.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Its very common to have a stored procedure returning data from multiple tables. The return type doesn't fit well under any of the Entity Types(Tables). Therefore if we define Complex Type as the return collection of objects from Stored Procedure invocation, it becomes quite a powerful tool for the developer.

Following these steps I have achieved successfully the configuration of complex type on a sample AdventureWorks database.
1. Refer the picture and ensure the Stored procedure and function import is done.
2. Add the Domain Service name it as AdventureDomainService.
3. Now its time to define the tell the RIA services framework to identify my Complex Type as Entity Type. To be able to do this, we need to identify a [Key] DataAnnotation. Entity types provide data structure to the application's data model and by design, each entity type is required to define a unique entity key. We can define key on one property or a set of properties in metadata class file AdventureDomainService.metadata.cs

First define the class then add MetadatatypeAttribute like :

---

[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(CTEmployeeManagers.CTEmployeeManagersMetadata))]
    public partial class CTEmployeeManagers
    {

```
    internal sealed class CTEmployeeManagersMetadata
    {
        private CTEmployeeManagersMetadata() { }
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int ManagerID { get; set; }
        public string ManagerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string ManagerLastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

4. Define the Domain service method to return the collection of objects/entities for populating the Silverlight Grid or any other data consuming controls.

---

```
public IQueryable<CTEmployeeManagers> GetEmployeeManagers(int empId)
    {
         return this.ObjectContext.GetEmployeeManagers(empId).AsQueryable();
    }
```

---

We define IQueryable if we are to fetch the records from datasources like SQL, whereas we define IEnumerable if we are to fetch the records from in memory collections,dictionaty,arrays.lists, etc.

5. Compile the server side to generate the client proxy.
6. In the Silverlight side open the MainPage.xaml or wherever the datagrid is put, then add following namespaces :

---

using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
using SLBusinessApplication.Web;
using SLBusinessApplication.Web.Services;

..

---

7. Load the data and display:

---

public partial class MyPage : Page
    {
        AdventureDomainContext ctx = new AdventureDomainContext();
        public MyPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadOperation loadOp =                   this.ctx.Load(this.ctx.GetEmployeeManagersQuery(29));
            myGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
        }

```
    // Executes when the user navigates to this page.
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

---

8. That is all that is needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be part of an entity. Complex types cannot be returned by themselves